# почему не используют `thread.sleep`?

Tags: java, многопоточность

прочитал на форумах, что `thread.sleep` лучше не использовать. почему?

Answer (score 3):

1. Особо плох не сам `Thread.sleep`, а polling - повторяющийся частый опрос чего-то в ожидании изменения состояния. Для уменьшения вредного эффекта (пожирания ресурсов) как раз и возможно применение `Thread.sleep`. Но это не решение проблемы, а борьба с последствиями. Но иногда без этого не обойтись.
2. `Thread.sleep` в других случаях плох тем, что впустую (блокировка на время "сна") тратится тяжеловесный `Thread`, в котором он исполняется. Если Thread'ов мало, то особых проблем нет. Но хуже, если их много, или они берутся из пула (ограниченного набора).

Альтернативой может быть использовании механизмов синхронизации, таймеров, отложенного исполнения, очередей или т.п.